# Why are Democrats relatively strong with rural areas in Michigan and Wisconsin?

Tags: united-states, demographics

People have wondered why Democrats are generally so strong in Vermont despite the state's history and having hostile demographics for Democrats. I found something interesting though less extreme, and comparable to Upstate New York and Oregon on this image:

[image]

Here is another image, compare to Ohio Pennsylvania and others:

[image: Source Twitter @ItsAkko]

The first image shows the votes in states' non urban areas where they are 89% white or more. This really stands out especially compared to their neighbors. Other states in this area have much greater Republican margins like Ohio and Kentucky, as does most of the other states shown west of New York. Why are Democrats so strong in these states?

Comment: Please link to the source of your image - or is this something you've created yourself?

Comment: https://disqus.com/by/rainbowjeremy01/ -- scroll through you'll find it

Comment: What is the definition “non-urban” here? Does it encompass both rural and suburban areas, which obviously are extremely different kinds of areas?

Comment: I think it means rural and ex-urban. Exurban is basically a rural suburban hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

Wisconsin and Michigan are generally blue states in a presidential election, 2016 was the only time either went red since 2000. This question doesn't make a ton of sense, both of these states were borderline Democratic strongholds under Obama. They both voted more Republican than the national average again in 2020. Republicans won the House vote in Wisconsin.  The second image shows pretty accurately the largest cities are blue, smaller cities are white, and anything not a suburb is red.

Comment: You can have a state that is actually a Democratic stronghold and have deep red rural areas, see Illinois.

Comment: @NumberFile voting more republican than average but still ultimately Democrat is still a democrat stronghold. Bucking the trend once in over 20 years is hardly a swing state.

Comment: A stronghold is when a state or region is won by a lot consistently. Winning by <1% for Wisconsin in 2000, 2004, 2016, and 2020 shows this is a clearly evenly divided swing state.